# Can't use "-" char to specify arguments in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

As the title said, whenever I try to specify an argument for a command using "-" (like `git log -r`) on powershell, the "-" char and everything after is read as a simple space char.
I can use dashes correcly if they are attached to other words.

I am using powershell on Windows 10 with oh-my-posh

Comment: Use `--%` to stop PowerShell parsing the arguments. => `git log --% -r`

Comment: Actually it was simpler than I thought: the color set for command arguments was the same as the background